# VBA code executes longer than usual for a particular combination

Tags: vba, optimization

I have the following VBA code which takes very long time when I execute it only for a particular region (San Diego).

The code runs smoothly for all the other regions.

```
    Sub Test()
    Range("A8:AQ1800").Clear

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   If Sheet4.Range("C1795").Value = False And Sheet4.Range("C1796").Value = True And Sheet4.Range("C1797").Value = True Then

Sheet1.Activate
    Range("F1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AR$1818").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "Clinic", "Medical Group", "Outpatient Surgi Center", "Owner Subsidiary", "="), _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues

     Range("B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AR$1818").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
    Sheet2.Range("B1").Value
    Range("A2:D2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheet2.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Select
    Range("B8").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A8").Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Range("D8").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Range("A8").Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Sheet1.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("G2:AR2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheet2.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Select
    Range("F8").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("F8").Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Range("H8").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Range("B8").Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select

    End If
```

The front end of **sheet2** looks like this. The check boxes beside 
Hospital
ASC
Others 
corresponds to the TRUE/FALSE options in the code

```
If Sheet4.Range("C1795").Value = True And Sheet4.Range("C1796").Value = False And Sheet4.Range("C1797").Value = False Then
```

[image: Sheet 2]

The front end for **Sheet1** looks like this.

[image]

The code takes very long to run only when I uncheck the box beside Hospital (False-True-True combination) for one location (San Diego, CA).

I don't understand if this is optimization problem because it does not happen for any other regions.

Thanks a lot in advance.

P.S. Let me know if I have provided sufficient information.

Comment: Just a tip: Get rid of Select  and Activate statements

Comment: Code that works is not meant for SO, I suggest you go to [Stackexchange - Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get help with optimization.

Answer (score 0):

the statements:

```
Range("A2:D2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

have the effect of selecting a range from "A2:D2" down to the first *non empty* **and** *visible* cell of column "A" in the currently active sheet (i.e. `Sheet1`).

thus, should the combination of:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AR$1818").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "Clinic", "Medical Group", "Outpatient Surgi Center", "Owner Subsidiary", "="), _
    Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

and:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AR$1818").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
Sheet2.Range("B1").Value
```

filter no rows **then ALL rows down to the last one would be selected**

---

Standing what above, the following statements:

`Sheet1.Activate
 ....
 ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AR$1818").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
    Sheet2.Range("B1").Value`

will filter range `"A1:AR1818"` of sheet `Sheet1` on its column `"F"` ("Territory") with the content of `Sheet2` cell `"B1"`.

as per your example the current value of this latter is *"San Diego, CA"*, while column `"F"` of `Sheet1` seems full of *numbers* (e.g.: "83") ...

assuming the rest (and yet not visibile in `Sheet1` pic) of column `"F"` hasn't any *"San Diego, CA"* values, then these subsequent statements:

```
Range("A2:D2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

have the effect of selecting cells in columns A:D from row 2 to the last one in the sheet!

I guess that `Sheet4` contains some *codification* of the value selected by the user in the `Sheet2` cell `"B1"` dropdown list into some *code number*

should this be the case then substitute:

```
 ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AR$1818").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
    Sheet2.Range("B1").Value`
```

with:

```
 ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AR$1818").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
    Sheet4.Range("xn").Value`
```

where you'd have to change that `"xn"` into the proper `Sheet4` cell reference

Comment: @Vinaybilla: did you get through it?